# child theme appears again when I put the header with parent name.

Tags: css, child-theme, customization

My wp site suddenly showed the default theme instead of its regular child-theme. Everyhing was restored when we put the parent theme name in the header of the style.css file. But the site was running correctly without that until that moment, our style.css didn't contain that syntax. Why did it happen? It can happen again so suddenly?? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child themes will not work correctly without the parent themes folder name being in the child themes `style.css` file header as the `Template Name:`

If this was missing, then someone must have removed it from the `style.css` file and it would have been in there previously if the site was working before.